# Issues with Eclipse while working on and Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

I am currently developing an application with my software engineering classmates. I am experiencing a few issues with Eclipse, however. But first, some information about my Eclipse: I am running version: Juno Service Release 2 with a build id of 20130225-0426. I am running Eclipse on my MacBook with OS X Mountain Lion 10.7.5. I am using SVN to upload and download the project to a repository through assembla.com.

First, Eclipse will not recognize any errors. If I purposely type random characters, Eclipse does not underline them with red.

Next, whenever I type "this.whatever" or "@ for javadoc" I receive the following message: "this compilation unit is not on the build path of a Java project." I can click "OK" and continue with no problem though.

Finally, whenever I attempt to run the program I receive this message:"The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

Other notes: I do not have any of these issues with any of my other projects in my workspace. I also have another project using the assembla repository that does not contain these issues. These issues just occurred all of the sudden.

Edit: None of the other members in my group are experiencing these issues. I have attempted to download the project from the repository on a different machine and I still have these problems. I have attempted to delete the project from my workspace and re-download. Still a no go.

Update: I even installed the Android Development Kit and used the included copy of Eclipse. It will still not work properly.

What is going on with my Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess you're in start phase of android coding and you're not addicted to a special IDE, I strongly recommend the `IntelliJ IDEA` instead of `Eclipse` for Android development. I have tried `Eclipse` already and because of its weaknesses, now I'm using `IntelliJ`. `Eclipse` is not the best IDE for Android development and have a long way to become the one.

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

Comment: I'm actually fairly far into the development project and would hate to switch over to a new IDE. But I will definitely look into IntelliJ IDEA for future projects!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [installing the ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) in a new location and see if you still have these problems.  The ADT bundle includes the latest Android SDK along with a version of Eclipse with the ADT (the Android Developer Tools plugin) already installed and configured.  It's possible that you have (or have had in the past) other Eclipse plugins that affect how the Java tools in Eclipse work, possibly in a way that interferes with ADT.  I have personally had problems like this in the past with tools like Aptana, where even after uninstalling there would be problems.

Comment: I have the Android SDK installed properly for Eclipse, which has been working fine up until now. I just don't understand why this project is giving me issue all the sudden. I have another Android project in the same workspace which works fine still.

Comment: Gotcha; I misunderstood your post.  In that case, could the project have been created as a Java project instead of as an Android project?  You could try deleting your current project (make sure "delete file contents on disk" is unchecked), then do File->Import->Android->Existing Android Code into Workspace. Another possibility is that someone you are working with screwed up the project settings (default.properties, project.properties or even something inside .metadata in the workspace directory if that is being checked in), then when you pulled from the repo you got the bad project settings.

Comment: No, I know for a fact the project was created as an Android application. The project works for all of the other group members working on the project. They can edit, compile, and run with no issues. I even went to a new machine (running Windows). Why would this only effect my repository user name?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is telling you already with the above error message: You don't have your sources on a build path, but just in some folder.

Either you have created a simple project instead of a Java project, which then also doesn't do anything Java specific. Or you have created your Java files in plain folders, instead of source folders.

The best way to sort this out is to [create a new Java project](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-3.htm?cp=1_1_0_1) using the Eclipse "New..." wizard from the main menu. Compare the result of that to your project. The two important things are: The project has an icon with a small "J" overlayed. The Java sources are shown in packages, which themself are in source folders (with a package overlay), not in simple folders.

[image]

Comment: The project was created as an Android application. The Java class was also written in the source folder.